# RelativeLayout transparency with ListView below

Tags: android

I have a relative layout with a transparent background. And a LinearLayout with a ListView below. The problem is, that I don't see my ListView below the transaprent RelativeLayout. Here's my xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/layoutabove"
     android:background="#55000000"   
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Login" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/myimage" />

    </RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

It's just black background.

Comment: You can be more clear, Right? please add image, how it looks now and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you have added black color in background of Listview/LinearLayout

Comment: Post your complete xml file so that we can look at parent view of your RelativeLayout and LinearLayout

Comment: probably its because you have give height match_parent to RelativeLayout

Comment: Your layout shows that you have added the two root layout in your xml which is not possible. There should be only a single root layout and inside that root layout your other layouts and views should be inserted. Or you have posted only half code of your layout

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below :

> ```
>  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>        android:id="@+id/layoutabove"
>        android:layout_width="match_parent"
>        android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:id="@+id/layoutabove"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:background="#55000000" >
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/loginbutton"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>         android:text="Login" />
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/image"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
>         android:src="@drawable/myimage" />
> </RelativeLayout>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:background="#000000"
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/layoutabove" >
>     <ListView
>         android:id="@+id/listView1"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
>     </ListView>
> </LinearLayout>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```